# Query regarding calculation of average of some numbers program

Tags: c#, math, c#-4.0

I am beginner in C# coding, and I am trying to write some code for the program where my program will show the average of numbers given by users. I have written below code, but I am thinking this would be more better and efficient. Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a=0;
            double total = 0;
            double result;
            Console.Write("For how many numbers you want to do the average calculation: ");
            a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double[] array = new double[a];
            for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter value for {0}: ", j+1);
                array[j]= double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            foreach (var item in array)
            {
                total += item;
            }
            result = total / a;
            Console.WriteLine($"Your Calculated average value is {result}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: In your example you don't have to store values into the array. Just add each value to the total as soon as you read it.

Comment: This *"would "* or this *"could"* ?

Comment: What's the title got to do with the question? I think using C# Expressions is beyond your experience but that's one way to do what the title asks

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for the misleading title, previously I was about to ask another question but I have ended with this.

Thanks for providing your feedback, will keep in mind. :)

Comment: Hi @Jim, many thanks for your feedback, will keep in mind from the next time. :)

Comment: Hi @ZoranHorvat

Many thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to take extra array for your purpose, you can do this just by adding each input value and then divide that total with total number of input items.

```
    double total = 0;
    double result;
    Console.Write("For how many numbers you want to do the average calculation: ");
    int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter value for {0}: ", j + 1);
        total += double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    result = total / a;
    Console.WriteLine($"Your Calculated average value is {result}");
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Accept answer, if it really helped u

Comment: Done. :) I am also new on stackoverflow so not aware about its options and process.

Comment: I'm also new, just ask good questions and try to give answers, you will learn a lot.